# Mount ext 4 read-only for old files and writable for new

Tags: mount, ext4, read-only

How can I mount ext 4 file system so that
"old files" mount in read-only and can't be deleted renamed attribute changed. But I can create "new files" in which I can write
delete change it name and attributes?
is this current possible or not(you must write yourself)?

Comment: Perhaps applying `chattr +i` to all the "old files" on mounting would achieve what you want? I haven't attempted to test it ...

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, that close to what i want.

Comment: ... another possibility might be to use an [overlay filesystem](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem)

Comment: A file system is either mounted read only or read write. However, you could mount rw but stop all current files being changed

Comment: @Mark how can i do that?

Comment: Steeldriver's `chattr +i` is what you probably want- see `man chattr`

Comment: with chattr +i, user can just chattr -i and delete file.So after chattr +i user must haven't opportunity to change "i" attribute. If user can change "i" attribute on his own file then "chattr "+i" " don't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you mount a volume as "Read Only" then it is read only. You can't write to a read only file system. You can only read and execute executables.

You can, however, control the permissions of individual files and folders with the `chmod` command, but I would caution against changing permissions for system files, application files, and configs, because you will break them.

Here's an example usage of `chmod`:

`chmod 444 file.txt`

This changes the permissions of the file `file.txt` to read only for owner, group, and public.

You can use a [chmod "calculator"](https://chmod-calculator.com/) to figure out the symbolic value for permissions in place of `444`.

Comment: i understand this, but is possible what i asked somehow?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: i understand how chmod working but what what meaning 
 " chmod "calculator" "?

Comment: oh no, i think this something in driver mode, not like chmod-calculator.com

Comment: idea is that you can't delete or changed(in user mode) files which already write to partition. So you can add only new and after unmount you cant change ever that files you added

Comment: When you change a file's permissions to read only they cannot be written to, so they can't be changed or deleted without explicit instructions to do so

Comment: i told about file system that work only for adding files.After "unmount" command files can't be changed ever by owner(on user layer)

Comment: i need this for incremental files backup. User must mount device,place incremental backup,umnout. After that ever user cant change or delete his backup(only root).

Comment: Can your backup software save the files as read only?

Comment: but if virus encrypt(delete,rewrite) them?

Comment: may be, but i want that it work as i want.May be that must work on samba server. So you mount samba server,  place incremental backup, unmount (but you can't change your previous backup).After that you mount samba again and verify data your placed before.

Comment: How does the file system or backups have anything to do with virus prevention?

Comment: if virus can run only on user mode but can't on root that scheme prevent backup damage